# Python code works in Ubuntu 14.04 but not in Win8.1

Tags: python, windows-8.1, ubuntu-14.04, attributeerror

I recieved [this code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0s3oyy8oefpoqwg/AABHYDWh8pzJxawwG8tKr6zqa?dl=0) of which I would like to run the script *runCortexReader.py* on my windows 8.1 operating system. Spyder gives me this error :

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SO_REUSEPORT'

The very same code works with Spyder on the same computer using Ubuntu 14.04 (using dual boot, not a virtual machine)

The problem is, that I really would like to run the script on Windows since it should later communicate with Matlab which is not installed on Ubuntu.

I'm using Python 2.7 on both systems.

Does anybody have an idea where the error could be?

Comment: Please add the complete traceback

Comment: What about a minimal running example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*SO_REUSEPORT* (and also *SO_REUSEADDR*) is a socket related setting. In [[SO]: How do SO_REUSEADDR and SO_REUSEPORT differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/how-do-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-differ), there's a good explanation for the differences between them.

*SO_REUSEPORT* is only present in newer Linux versions - defined in */usr/include/asm-generic/socket.h* to a value of 15 typically (`#define SO_REUSEPORT    15`):

- Is defined in *Ubuntu 14*, but not in *Ubuntu 12* (the line is commented out: `/* To add :#define SO_REUSEPORT 15 */`)
- Is defined in *RHEL 7*, but not in *RHEL 5* (same comment)

On *Win* on the other hand, there's no such macro defined in *Visual Studio*'s include files (typically *Winsock2.h*).

Also, [[MS.Docs]: setsockopt function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-setsockopt) doesn't mention it in the possible option names.

What you'll have to do in order to get it working on *Win* (although it's not a nice approach), is to comment out (by adding a ***#*** char at the beginning) all the lines that reference it (I found it on the following file, but it might be present in other ones):

- *CortexDecoder.py* line 244:

  ```py
  self.cortexSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
  ```

or (**this is even dirtier**) in the same file(s), after importing the *socket* module, add this line:

```py
socket.SO_REUSEPORT = socket.SO_REUSEADDR
```